# Using firewalld rich rules to drop loopback packets with specific source and destination ports

Tags: firewalld

I am running several software components communicating with each other through different ports on a single machine.
one of them is a kernel module.
I want to simulate network disconnections between them.
can I use firewalld with rich rules to drop packets that come from one port and designated to another?

I have tried

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source-port port=50778 protocol=tcp drop'
```

which works, but blocks one component from all others and I only want to simulate on-to-one disconnection.
if I add any other port field in this line I get an error.

can I do that using firewalld? or should I use iptables or others instead?